# R Shiny: Updating an output before another (relatively long) computation is finished

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following problem. My shiny app is basically doing the following on the server side after a button is clicked:

```
observe({

isolate({
## Here are a lots of computations with the results shown iteratively using invalidateLater():
})

if( computations not done ){
   invalidateLater(500)
} else {
   #Once the computations are done, I create a final output table and also a image.
   output$example <- renderTable( something based on the computations )
   output$example2 <- renderPlot( something based on the computations )

   #Here comes code to save the results of the computation in a database

})
```

Here is my problem: Saving to the database takes like 3 seconds. This isn't the end of the world, but my problem is that the final output is only rendered **after** the saving is finished.

I'd like to change this, that is I'd like to first render the output (which really doesn't take long, maybe half a second). I tried different things like putting saving code into another observe and/or isolate block, but I couldn't get it done. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Let's say you can get it to do that. What happens if the user closes the app before the 3 seconds is up? Database is not updated?